# Split JSON data frame into multiple column in R

Tags: r, json

I have a JSON file. I already readLines

```
lines = readLines("D:/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd.json")
lines = lapply(lines, fromJSON)
lines = lapply(lines, unlist)
a1 = bind_rows(lines)
```

After readLines I got this

[image]

Now I want to split into multiple columns
Expected output:

| price_ori | delivery | item_category_detail |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5.52 | KL City | Health & Beauty |
| 3.40 | KL City | Health & Beauty |
| 14.90 | KL City | Health & Beauty |

Comment: Please post sample of json for [mcve].

Comment: You could post a link to the data if its shareable. Or eve part of the data. Or simply copy the first few lines of your `json` and post it here

Answer (score 2):

Since it appears your JSON is relatively flat with a *data* key on each line, consider running `fromJSON` directly on the text file. Note: below is untested, guessing at the structure of R object built from json. Assess with `str` and adjust as needed.

```r
obj <- fromJSON("D:/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd.json")
str(obj)  # ASSESS STRUCTURE TO FIND data ELEMENT

df_list <- lapply(obj, "[[", "data")

final_df <- bind_rows(df_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the data using function `fromJSON`:

```r
library(jsonlite)
fromJSON("test.json")$data
```

You should see the data formatted like this:

| price_ori | delivery |
| --- | --- |
| 123.123 | delivery1 |
| 122.22 | delivery2 |